# C# Windows Forms Application: Change behavior of all instances of a control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, numericupdown

I would like to change the increment values and decimal places for all of my numeric updowns.

I know I can do this individually [with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

`numericUpDownName.DecimalPlaces = 2;` and `numericUpDownName.Increment = 0.01M;`

What is the best approach to do this efficiently? I could create methods in Form1.cs for each numeric updown but that seems pretty bulky.

[I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074356/add-behavior-to-group-of-windows-form-controls) creating a subclass that inherits numeric updowns but I'm still not sure how I can utilize it to make all the controls work the same way without having to initialize each numeric updown as member of that class in Form1.cs.

```
class numberInput : NumericUpDown { }
```

[image: this is what I'm dealing with, most of these will be hidden in a practical use case, max case]

Comment: Did you manually add all those `NumericUpDown` controls to the form or are you creating them with code and then adding them to the form?

Comment: Create a constructor for you subclass and in the constructor put : this.numericUpDownName.DecimalPlaces = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating all those `NumericUpDown` controls? If you're doing it in the designer, then that's the place to set the properties to what you want.

If you're creating them programmatically, then change the properties there instead.

If for some reason you can't do either of those things (but why?) then you could use reflection to set them all like so. This method assumes that it will be a member of the form containing the `NumericUpDown` controls, and that the controls are all at the top level (i.e. not contained in a `Panel` or other such container control):

```
void setNumericUpDownProperties()
{
    foreach (var numericUpDown in this.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>())
    {
        numericUpDown.DecimalPlaces = 2;
        numericUpDown.Increment = 0.01M;
    }
}
```

(This requires `using System.Linq;`)

You would call that after the call to `InitializeComponent()` in the form's constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I added them all manually, so the solution was to select them all in the designer and change the properties. I never noticed those values in the properties tab before, thank you for leading me in the right direction.